# setPluginState and setPluginsEnabled

Tags: android

My Android app was first intended for Android 2.2 onwards so I used

```
player.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```

for the WebView object.

Now that I've decided to open my app to Android 2.1 users, I changed my code to this:

```
try {
  player.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
} catch (Exception e) {
  player.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
}
```

With this, the app force closes and I get this error on my logcat:

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.webkit.WebSettings$PluginState
    at com.dokgu.joindota.WatchVOD.onCreate(WatchVOD.java:34)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help with this error?

EDIT:
This error only appears on the 2.1 emulator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit late - I'm sure you've figured it out by now - but the error is caused by the class `PluginState` not being available on Android versions < 2.2 (API 8). See [the android docs on PluginState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.PluginState.html).

The reason why you can't catch this with `try {} catch (Exception e) {}` is because the `NoClassDefFoundError` is not an [`Exception`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Exception.html) - it's an [`Error`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Error.html). While `Error` and `Exception` are both children of [`Throwable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable.html) they are not the same, hence you cannot catch an `Error` with an `Exception` and vice versa.

To solve this you can take either of the following approaches:

1. Check which Android version the device is running, and only call `PluginState` when the device is running API-version >= 8.
2. In your `catch()`-statement, catch `NoClassDefFoundError` instead of `Exception`.

Also, Eclipse will most likely show a Lint-warning mentioning the `PluginState`-class is only available on API 8+. You can hide/ignore this warning by adding `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` to the line above your method.

Comment: setPluginState method of WebSettings is also deprecated in [Api level 18 or higher]

Comment: So whats the solution then? I want to show Flash Content on Webview on Api 22

Comment: Any solution for this?