# WebView setPluginsEnabled and setPluginState handling for versions 7 to 19

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an app which supports versions starting from api 7. Till now, I have been using below code for webview plugin settings:
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
            webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        } else {
            webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        }`

But now I have changed my targetSdkVersion to 19 and the line `webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);` gives compilation error when compiled using Android build target 4.4.2.
 How to handle the plugins settings across all the versions from api 7 to api 19 ? Should I remove the code or do something else ? 
 I have already referred following links:
[setPluginsEnabled not exist for WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362049/setpluginsenabled-not-exist-for-webview)
[setPluginState and setPluginsEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959851/setpluginstate-and-setpluginsenabled)